# QwtScaleWidget::scaleDivChanged is working only with old syntax

Tags: qt, qwt

I inherit my class from `QwtPlot`. Now I am trying to get a signal when axis limits are changed and autoscale is enabled. In Qt forum I found a proposal to use `scaleDivChanged` signal from `QwtScaleWidget`:

```
connect(axisWidget(...), SIGNAL(scaleDivChanged()), ... );
```

And this works, but only when old syntax is used. When I try to write in new way:

```
connect(axisWidget(...), &QwtScaleWidget::scaleDivChanged, [&]{...});
```

I receive the following error:

```
QObject::connect: signal not found in QwtScaleWidget
```

Why this signal is working with old syntax, and not working with the new one? I checked from source code, and didn't find any reason for this.